# Convergence of a Newton series (of import to the theory of Mellin transforms and fractional calculus)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, interpolation

Laguerre expansion with the Laguerre polynomials

$$L_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}\frac{x^{k}}{k!}= \triangledown_{k=0}^{n} \frac{x^k}{k!}  $$

formally gives

$$\frac{x^{s-1}}{(s-1)!}= \sum_{n \geq 0} L_n(x) \int_0^\infty e^{-t} L_n(t) \frac{t^{s-1}}{(s-1)!}dt $$

$$= \sum_{n \geq 0}(-1)^n \binom{s-1}{n} L_n(x)= \triangledown_{n=0}^{s-1}L_n(x) =\triangledown_{n=0}^{s-1}\triangledown_{k=0}^{n} \frac{x^k}{k!} $$

$$=  \int_0^\infty e^{-t}[\sum_{n \geq 0} L_n(x) L_n(t)] \frac{t^{s-1}}{(s-1)!}dt=  \int_0^\infty \delta(x-t)  \frac{t^{s-1}}{(s-1)!}dt .$$

Norlund in his book Lecons sur les Series d'Interpolation (1926, p. 165) established that

$$\frac{x^{s-1}}{(s-1)!}= \triangledown_{n=0}^{s-1}\triangledown_{k=0}^{n} \frac{x^k}{k!} $$

holds for $x >0$ and $Re(s) > 1/4$.

Wigert had shown earlier in "[Contributions à la théorie des polynômes d'Abel-Laguerre](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc1.%7Bb156356c-3909-46b8-9031-372ac2dbb750%7Db523827&view=1up&seq=555)" [Arkiv for Matematik, Astronomi och Fysik (Stockholm), t. XV, 1921, no. 25] on pp. 16-7, (frames 595-6)] that the Newton series identity holds for $s > 1$. Furthermore, in  "[Sur une transformation de la série $\sum_{n} a_n \binom{s}{n}$][2]" [Arkiv Mat. Astr. och Fysik (Stockholm), t. VII, no. 26, 1911, p. 1 (frame 555)], he claims that the Newton series

$$\triangledown_{n = 0}^s a_n$$

and the Dirichlet series

$$\sum_{n \geq 1} (-1)^n \frac{a_n}{n^{s+1}}$$

have the same domain of convergence.

**Question**:

Is the Newton series identity

$$\frac{x^{s-1}}{(s-1)!}= \triangledown_{n=0}^{s-1}\triangledown_{k=0}^{n} \frac{x^k}{k!} $$

valid for $0 < Re(s) \leq 1/4$?

Comment: Link for second WIgert paper is https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc1.$b523827&view=1up&seq=555

Comment: the latter result ($\triangledown_{n = 0}^s a_n$ and $\sum_{n \geq 1} (-1)^n \frac{a_n}{n^{s+1}}$ have same radius of convergence is a Theorem of Landau and is easily proven using the theory of Newton series (Norlund gives a proof in the cited book starting from page 112 - Newton series have an abscissa of convergence like Dirichlet series and it is an exercise in Abel transform to show that the formula in terms of coefficients $a_n$ - both Norlund and Landau shift $s$ by $1$ so the formulas are the same for $a_n$ as given - is the same as for the Dirichlet series with coefficients $(-1)^na_n$

Comment: @Conrad, yes,  Wigert references Landau also. Both W & N were aware of the standard convergence theories of their time, so I wonder why Norlund achieved a larger  convergence domain than Wigert and if the domain can be extended further to zero (mainly for esthetic sentiments). The summation for the Dirichlet series is more stable numerically than the Newton, but both series truncated to large order appear either slowly convergent or divergent near zero.

Comment: for the original question, I think that the formula $93$ on page 163 in Norlund shows that the appropriate $\limsup$ is precisely $1/4$ so by the above result the abscissa of convergence of the Newton series $F_x(s)=1+\sum_{m \ge 1}(-1)^mL_m(x)\frac{(s-1)\cdots(s-m)}{m!}, x>0$ is precisely $1/4$ so the answer to your question is negative; as for the question in your comment, Norlund uses the Fejer-Perron asymptotic $93$, so maybe Wigert wasn't aware of it

Comment: As for Landau original proof is in the link below; while in German (and personally never studied german), I find Landau's texts very easy to understand http://publikationen.badw.de/de/020287440

Comment: @Conread, thanks for the link. It wasn't clear to me that Norlund had established an if-and-only-if (conditional or otherwise) convergence criterion. If so, question answered, and can you point me to a ref in English on this particular criterion?

Comment: The book of Norlund proves it as noted - I have no idea about a reference in English (but I read French and I think the proof is fairly straightforward - it's a bit confusing as Norlund uses variable $z$ and index $s$ but that's no big deal) - it starts on page 112

Comment: @Conrad, I'm not fluent in French, less so in German, so I'll take your word for it that it is a necessary and sufficient condition. Btw, those interested in general convergence criteria  and summability might also find "Interpolation series" by R. Creighton Buck useful.